# How to extend functionality of .Net wrapper for scrcpy written in C?

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

Started looking at [scrcpy (original in C)](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy), an Android screen mirroring utility through ADB - works fine on my system.

I have found a [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pvdstel.scrcpy) which I have successfully installed, appearing in the VS installed extensions list.

I have also downloaded and ran the [source code](https://github.com/pvdstel/scrcpy-vs/) in VS.

The issue is that when I run the solution, it opens up a new instance of VS and I'm not quite sure how to make use of this extension.

It's supposed to be a wrapper around scrcpy and I see the C# code that does the work.  Ultimately I would like to begin extending its current features/functionalities with C# which is what I require assistance with please.

In terms of debugging a .vsix extension, I have ensured the [following measures](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/VSIXextensionmodel/) have been taken, i.e. the Debug configuration starts "devenv.exe /rootsuffix Exp".

---

If you're going to down-vote, please at least comment as to why.  I have a valid issue here in trying to get this working.

Comment: You're using VS2010?  That's pretty old, have you tried a newer version?  VS2017 Community is free now.

Comment: I'm using VS 2019.  I updated the extension manifest and .json to install on 2019.

Comment: As it seems that you found some direction: https://github.com/pvdstel/scrcpy-vs/issues/5 You should either update this question (perhaps with what you've found/tried/seeking to actually do), self answer, or close the question.